# How to fetch mail using imap on PHP

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to read email with PHP. Here is my code :

```
$inbox = imap_open($host, $username, $password) or die(print_r(imap_errors(), true));
```

But this is what i'm getting :

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream mail.myserver.com in
>   /home/myserver/public_html/myscript.php on line 18 Array ( [0] => Can't
>   open mailbox mail.myserver.com: no such mailbox )

The credentials $host, $username and $password are right.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: First parameter isn't the host, but a [mailbox string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php), can you show its (anonymized) value?

Comment: @msg, i simply want to access the inbox from the email account on mail.myserver.com, what should i put then ?

Comment: It depends on the features used by the server, refer to the docs. The bare minimum should be the host **enclosed in `{}`**

Comment: It worked now after i put the server between {}. Thank you ! :D